# Loop divisible by issue

Tags: loop, index

Code:

```
{% for block in entry.testimonials %}
  <div class="col-24 {% if loop.last %}gutter-bottom{% else %}gutter-bottom--none{% endif %}">
    <div class="section inner">
      <div class="col-17 {% if loop.index0 is not divisible by(2) %}last float-right {% endif %}">
        {% switch block.type %}

        {% case "testimonials" %}

          <h3>{{ block.personsName }}</h3>
          {{ block.quote }}
          </div>

          {% for asset in block.image %}

            <div class="col-7 circle-image-container {% if loop.index0 is divisible by(2) %}last{% endif %}">
              <img src="{{ asset.getUrl() }}"  alt="{{ asset.title }}"/>
            </div>

          {% endfor %}

        {% endswitch %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Can anyone point out why the...

```
loop.index0 is divisible by(2)
```

I have on the div around the image isn't working. I'm getting the 'last' class on everything. The one on the previous div is working fine.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I've just realised it's in it's own image loop causing the problem. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 5):

Forgive me if I'm wrong... by using `loop.index0 is divisible by(2)` are you trying to determine if the instance is odd or even?

- 1st - returns `false`
- 2nd - returns `true`
- 3rd - returns `false`
- 4th - returns `true`

If so Twig does support checking if the loop index is even or odd. Perhaps that would be better to use?

```
{% if loop.index is even %}Even{% endif %}
```

**EDIT**

I've just had a read of the [Craft docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/switch) for the Case and Switch tags and found this:

> If you’re using the {% switch %} tag inside of a {% for %} loop, you won’t be able to access Twig’s loop variable directly inside of the {% switch %} tag. Instead, you can access it like so:

```
{% for matrixBlock in entry.matrixField %}
    {% set loopIndex = loop.index %}

    {% switch matrixBlock.type %}

        {% case "text" %}

            Loop #{{ loopIndex }}

    {% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that is easier but I still have the same problem of it returning the same for all of them

Comment: @sarah3585 Just updated my answer with some information I found on the Craft docs, perhaps that will resolve your issue?

Answer (score 4):

What you want is not the [loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) of the inner loop around the image, but the loop variable of the outer loop. To get to the outer loop, use `loop.parent`. Try this:

```
{% if loop.parent.loop.index0 is divisible by(2) %}last{% endif %}
```